# Protools8 - PT10

Tags: pro-tools

I’m running Protools 8 LE with DV toolkit 2 on a pc (windows xp).

I’m going to buy a new pc and I have a few queries regarding PT10.

On my new pc I would like to upgrade to PT10 using windows 7.

1) If I go with the upgrade from DV toolkit 2 to PT10 without the complete production tool kit will I get
the following included: DINR, TL Space and XForm (which all came with DV Toolkit 2)

2) Without paying for two PT programs is it possible to continue to use DV toolkit 2 on my old PC and 
PT 10 on my new pc even if it meant pluging in and out the ilok dongle?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to #1: All the bundled plug-ins are separate licenses on your iLok. I don't believe they're tied to a particular version number, so they should carry over.

**WRONG ->** [In answer to #2: No. Upgrading to 10 will require you to surrender your license for 8.] **See @stavrosound's comments below (thanks for correcting me, man).**

Comment: Isn't 8 tied to the hardware? So you should be able to run the 2 versions of Protools on different systems.

Comment: 

@Tak - 8 requires a license on an iLok, in addition to the hardware. without that license you can't run 8, period...and a license for 10 will not allow you to run 8

Comment: @Shaun  Slightly incorrect. I still run 8 LE and there's no iLok asset required for it - the 'authentication' is hardware/serial number.  Hardware in terms of running a Digi box or mBox.  If he had 8 HD, then you would be correct that it is tied to an iLok.  I believe 9 was the first version where the LA/regular version begin using iLok since Digi dropped the proprietary hardware requirements.

Comment: I believe that's also why they charge more to 'crossgrade' to 10 from 8 versus a simple version upgrade cost since there's nothing being surrendered as collateral like an iLok asset.  I could be wrong on this, although I remember always referring to my serial number I store in the manual cover and don't recall ever being asked or offered at purchase time or anywhere in the documentation that 8 LE ran from iLok.

Comment: @Stavrosound - thanks for that info. @Tak - Sorry for giving you inaccurate information.